# Formula of estimation time for encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, time, formula, estimation

Is there any mathematical formula to estimate the encryption time for an encryption algorithm (RSA, SHA, any...) depending on data volume. (The computer or network characteristics and performances could be fixed).

If you 're sure that there isn't please inform me to stop searching.

Comment: All modern crypto algorithms I'm aware of have complexity that is linear in the length of the data to be processed, for a given keysize. The typical basic quantum to measure is the block. The total time is then the product of this time with the number of blocks in the data. For example, AES has a block size of 16 bytes, RSA has a block size of log2(modulus) bits, and hash algorithms have block sizes that vary depending on the hash algorithm.

Comment: thanks for your help..the problem is that I have a graph which contain response time of my DB while excuting some SQL or OLAP queries and I want to compare it with the respone time in case of encryption. what do you suggest?

Answer (score -1):

Write a function that calls the encryption function and before the call to encryption function and after that get the timestamp from time()
Take the difference between the two timestamps and you are good to go.

Comment: Do you know any java function or method to encrypt a ResultSet